# Bluetooth keyboard always wants to pair

Tags: macos, keyboard, mac, macbook-pro, bluetooth

I have a MacBook Air in my office that prompts to pair to a BlueTooth keyboard every 5-10 seconds.

I turned BlueTooth off/on. Made sure it is not discoverable. Restarted. Run updates. Reset PRAM. Reset SMC. Deleted com.apple.bluetooth.plist (~/Library/Preferenes/ and /Library/Preferences/). Removed the offending  and  from the above plists. With no luck.

I have also taken another computer up next to the MacBook Air running iStumblr as well as the Set Up Bluetooth keyboard and the keyboard cannot be found by either the MacBook Air or the other Mac. But the prompts still persist on the Air.

I have not been able to find any other suggestions re: how to stop the prompts.

Finding the keyboard is going to prove tricky as it is in a large office environment.

Any other suggestions?

EDIT: Console

```
11/03/14 3:11:28.000 PM kernel[0]: ### ERROR: opCode = 0x0406 (Disconnect) -- send request failed (err=0x0012 (kBluetoothHCIErrorInvalidHCICommandParameters))
11/03/14 3:11:28.000 PM kernel[0]: [0xffffff8016117200][free]()
11/03/14 3:11:31.000 PM kernel[0]: ### ERROR: opCode = 0x0406 (Disconnect) -- send request failed (err=0x0012 (kBluetoothHCIErrorInvalidHCICommandParameters))
11/03/14 3:11:31.000 PM kernel[0]: [0xffffff8013f74700][free]()
11/03/14 3:11:40.000 PM kernel[0]: [0xffffff8014ae4200][free]()
11/03/14 3:11:40.000 PM kernel[0]: ### ERROR: opCode = 0x0406 (Disconnect) -- send request failed (err=0x0012 (kBluetoothHCIErrorInvalidHCICommandParameters))
11/03/14 3:11:44.000 PM kernel[0]: ### ERROR: opCode = 0x0406 (Disconnect) -- send request failed (err=0x0012 (kBluetoothHCIErrorInvalidHCICommandParameters))
11/03/14 3:11:44.000 PM kernel[0]: [0xffffff801409d800][free]()
11/03/14 3:11:52.457 PM coreaudiod[149]: Disabled automatic stack shots because audio IO is active
11/03/14 3:11:52.631 PM coreaudiod[149]: Enabled automatic stack shots because audio IO is inactive
11/03/14 3:11:54.718 PM librariand[657]: MMe quota status changed: under quota
11/03/14 3:11:54.862 PM com.apple.security.pboxd[661]: Bug: 12F45: liblaunch.dylib + 23849 [2F71CAF8-6524-329E-AC56-C506658B4C0C]: 0x25
```

Comment: Does it show the BT running in the Activity monitor. Could you also look in the Console and publish few lines of interest.

Comment: Yes Bluetooth is running in the Activity Monitor. Updated OP with Console log.

Comment: Try going to System Preferences > Bluetooth, then finding the keyboard, right clicking on it, and clicking "Remove"

Comment: The keyboard only appears in the System Preferences > Bluetooth when it prompts to pair, then disappears, and then reappears. I have hit reject on the prompt, and also tried to remove it in System Preferences but the prompts continue. I am now looking into Bluetooth Explorer (Xcode Hardware IO Tool).

Answer (score 1):

Your Console shows:

1- The kernel is trying to turn off BT but gets refused!

2- Your os x install has a bug?

They might or not be related.

Reinstall your OS X (12F45) update. ->Check.

Reset your SMC. ->Check.

If problem continues Log in as Guest. ->Check.

Comment: Reinstalled 12F45. Reset SMC. Issue still occurs. Ran Bluetooth Explorer, reset Connected Apple HID Devices, Full Factory Reset connected Apple Devices, Delete Link Keys from Bluetooth Module, Delete global preference file, Delete All Keys from local software stores, Remove all favourite devices, Unconfigure all configured devices, restart blueooth daemon, restart. Issue still occurs. Rebooted MacBook Air on known good OS, issue still occurs.

Comment: Darn, a hard one :)

Comment: Yea, I think I'm resigned to tracking down the troublesome keyboard :(

Comment: it can only be in a 30 feet radius :) did the OS X bug go away in process ?

Comment: I've just tried walking about the building with my Mac laptop with BTScanner (Windows software), iStumblr, and then Setup Bluetooth Keyboard. And I can't detect the keyboard at all. What ties that keyboard to the MacBook Air? It isn't paired, but it connects automatically.